# python display map with googlemaps

Tags: python, google-maps

I found a [googlemaps](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) package to access google map from python,but didn't find any demo to show the result in python code.

For example:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Geocoding an address
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')

# Look up an address with reverse geocoding
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((40.714224, -73.961452))

# Request directions via public transit
now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions("Sydney Town Hall",
                                     "Parramatta, NSW",
                                     mode="transit",
                                     departure_time=now)
```

I can print the directions_result to console but don't know how to show the map in graphic mode. How to show the search result as a map in python?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because **googlemaps** package is only for data/responses API.

---

For more information read this tutorial (writing JS map & data analysis): https://github.com/invisibleroads/invisibleroads-tutorials/blob/master/geodjango-googlemaps-build.rst

---

For plotting data on google maps use: https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot